# Why delegate item center is draw at start position of Path?

Tags: qt, qml

When I learn about `PathView`,I found the first and last delegate item center point is draw at the `Path`.

I think the first delegate item `x y` poszition should be same `startX startY`,but actually it is not?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: root
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Canvas {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d")
            ctx.lineWidth = 1
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#abc"
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.moveTo(0,0)
            ctx.lineTo(root.width, root.height)
            ctx.stroke()
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: myDelegate
        Rectangle {
            width: 100; height: 100
            color: "#321"
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: index
            }
        }
    }

    PathView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 2
        delegate: myDelegate
        path: Path {
            startX: 0; startY: 0
            PathLine{relativeX: root.width; relativeY: root.height}
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: the first item is exactly at (0,0) considering that origin point of an delegate in its center.

Comment: @folibis I think that causes the confusion, are there any docs where it indicates that the (0,0) is relative to the center of the delegate? I would expect it to be the topleft

Comment: @eyllanesc if the  (0,0) is first posiztion of path, why my first delegate item center point at   (0,0) of the path?

Comment: @eyllanesc, as you notices in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102980/can-i-controll-the-attachment-point-of-a-delegate-to-a-pathview-in-qml) question, [transformOrigin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#transformOrigin-prop) by default is `Item.Center` so I guess that's the reason. I guess that when `PathView` applies transformation to the Rectangle it relies on `transformOrigin`.